# Can the radius be solved with just this information?

Tags: circles

[image: Try to find the Radius]

All the information that I have is that the arc starts at 357.5° which is 6mm from the outer possible reach.  Is it possible to calculate the radius of the circle with this information.

Comment: Hint: $cos(a)=\frac{r-b}{r}$

Comment: @Leafar Because the angle $a$ starts at the $y$-axis, wouldn't that be $\sin (a)=\frac{r-b}{r}$?

Comment: @Axoren The OP states that the radius, $r$ is what he is looking for.  The picture may be faulty.

Comment: The hypotenuse would be equal the radius. My drawing is a bit off on showing the exact location of where the 6mm is measured from. I believe his hint is correct. This 6mm point is located on edge of the circle, (r) distance from the center.

Comment: @PaulSundheim I agree with your hint upon closer inspection. It should be $\sin$, not $\cos$.

Comment: Of course my fault

Comment: So would you agree that  r= 1/( (sin(a)-1) /b )